# Awk for each column compare consecutive rows and add value

Tags: awk

I searched for related questions, but cannot find an appropriate answer for my problem. For example, I have a file of 6 rows and 3 columns.

```
id  sample1 sample2  sample3
6   +/+      +/+      +/-
16  -/-      +/+      +/+
20  +/-      +/+      +/+
21  +/-      +/+      +/+
22  +/+      +/+      -/-
25  +/+      +/+      +/+
```

For each column, I need to compare the string of one row with the string in the next one, and based on the values, report a number with AWK, based on the following comparison table (no matter the order of field1 and field2):

```
field1   field2   value
 +/+      +/+       0
 +/+      +/-       0.5
 +/-      +/-       1
 +/+      -/-       2
 +/-      -/-       2.5
 -/-      -/-       4
```

Desired output is thus:

```
id  sample1 sample2 sample3 result1  result2    result3
6   +/+      +/+      +/-     2        0           0.5
16  -/-      +/+      +/+     2.5      0           0
20  +/-      +/+      +/+     1        0           0
21  +/-      +/+      +/+     0.5      0           2
22  +/+      +/+      -/-     0 0      2
25  +/+      +/+      +/+
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 1):

another similar `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1,$2]=a[$2,$1]=$3; next}
       FNR==1  {print $0,"result1","result2","result3"; next}
               {print f0, a[f[2],$2], a[f[3],$3], a[f[4],$4]; 
                f0=$0; split($0,f)}
       END     {print}' score file | column -t

id  sample1  sample2  sample3  result1  result2  result3
6   +/+      +/+      +/-      2        0        0.5
16  -/-      +/+      +/+      2.5      0        0
20  +/-      +/+      +/+      1        0        0
21  +/-      +/+      +/+      0.5      0        2
22  +/+      +/+      -/-      0        0        2
25  +/+      +/+      +/+
```

Comment: Great solution. I'm just trying to figure out how it could work, if there are a variable number of columns. Thanks for your help.

Comment: for variable number of columns you need to replace print statements with for loop and printf.

Answer (score 0):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{ if (NR > 1) a[$1$2] = $3; next }
     FNR == 1{ print $0, "result1\tresult2\tresult3"; next }
     id{ 
         print id, s2, s3, s4, 
               (a[$2 s2] == ""? a[s2 $2] : a[$2 s2]),
               (a[$3 s3] == ""? a[s3 $3] : a[$3 s3]),
               (a[$4 s4] == ""? a[s4 $4] : a[$4 s4]) 
     }
     { id = $1; s2 = $2; s3 = $3; s4 = $4 }
     END{ print $0 }' table.txt OFS='\t' data.txt | column -t
```

The output:

```
id  sample1  sample2  sample3  result1  result2  result3
6   +/+      +/+      +/-      2        0        0.5
16  -/-      +/+      +/+      2.5      0        0
20  +/-      +/+      +/+      1        0        0
21  +/-      +/+      +/+      0.5      0        2
22  +/+      +/+      -/-      0        0        2
25  +/+      +/+      +/+
```

Comment: Consider `split($0,p)` (`p` for `prev`) and `p[1]`, `p[2]`, `p[3]`, `p[4]` instead of multiple hard-coded scalar variables `id = $1; s2 = $2; s3 = $3; s4 = $4` and `id`, `s2`, `s3`, `s4`.